# How come my table doesn't have lines around the rows and colums?

Tags: html

I'm very new to HTML so please excuse me if this question is very simple.

I created a table using . When I look at my table there are no lines anyplace. Is there I can make lines appear around the cells?

Answer (score 3):

A basic table implementation would be:

```
<table border=1>
 <thead><tr><td>#</td><td>Name</td></tr></thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>One</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>Two</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td><td>Three</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td><td>Four</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

however, through CSS styling you can do more sleek borders like:

```
<table cellspacing=0 style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
 <thead><tr><td>#</td><td>Name</td></tr></thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>One</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>Two</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td><td>Three</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td><td>Four</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That CSS example won't render borders around the rows and columns, only the entire table.

Comment: it was just an example to show how it works as the guy is new to HTML. Of course it wouldn't set border for each table cell.

Answer (score 1):

With the [CSS border property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#border-properties)

Opera have [a web standards tutorial](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/1-introduction-to-the-web-standards-cur/#toc) that includes a large section on CSS if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    /* border-width border-style border-color */
}
```

You could use long hand versions as well, of course:

```
td, th {
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid; /* double, dashed, dotted... */
    border-top-color: #ccc;
}
```

And the same for `border-left`, `border-right` and `border-bottom`...